# Saving audit data to database asynchronously in asp.net webforms application

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, asynchronous

I have an asp.net 3.5 web application which generates alot of audit related data. Since that data isn't immediately relevant to the user, I'd like to be able to save it to the MSSQL database asynchronously and let the user go onto the next page without waiting. I'm using Nhibernate as my ORM.

I've looked into PageAsyncTasks and as far as I can tell they simply allow you to perform page operations in parallel, but all operations still have to complete before the page finishes loading. Is there an alternative, fairly lightweight method to have asynchronous processing that will continue on without affecting page load? Is simply spinning up a new thread manually an acceptable process?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a web service within your solution and when your server-side code is finished and ready to move the user on to the next page it could call your web service to do the auditing as a fire and forget type thing.

Not sure if the NHibernate session is threadsafe so if you create a new thread be careful with the  context.

Ideally you could use queues and a servicebus to deal with this sort of thing safely and async but that involves architectural changes.

Not sure if this is possible but if the auditing is actually noticeably slowing the UI down maybe you'd be better off to improve that process and keep it synchronous. Either way, good luck.